# Convert ADODB::Recordset^ to _RecordsetPtr

Tags: c#, c++, adodb, recordset

I'm using a C# dll inside in C++/CLI wrapper. The dll is returning an ADODB::Recordset^ object, but I need the wrapper to return a _RecordsetPtr object.
How can I convert between the two?

Here's what I have so far. The problem I'm running in to is that after the last line of the for-loop, the function skips to the return statement and ends. It doesn't continue looping, and it doesn't hit the "Object^ rows = . . ." line.

```
_RecordsetPtr TraserInterface::GetDistributorRecordset()
{
    ADODB::Recordset^ recordset = TraserWrapper::Instance->traserInterface->DistributorRecordset;
    ADODB::Fields^ fields = ((ADODB::RecordsetClass^)recordset)->default;
    HRESULT hr;
    _RecordsetPtr recordsetPtr("ADODB.Recordset");
    for (int i = 0; i < fields->Count; i++)
    {
        ADODB::Field^ field = fields[i];
        String^ fieldName = field->Name;
        _bstr_t bstrName = MarshalString(fieldName).c_str();
        int type = (int)field->Type;
        int definedSize = field->DefinedSize;
        int fieldAttrib = field->Attributes;
        hr = recordsetPtr->Fields->Append(bstrName, (DataTypeEnum)type, definedSize, (FieldAttributeEnum)fieldAttrib);
    }
    Object^ rows = recordset->GetRows((int)ADODB::GetRowsOptionEnum::adGetRowsRest, (Object^)ADODB::BookmarkEnum::adBookmarkFirst, (Object^)fields);
    // loop through rows and populate recordsetPtr . . .
    return recordsetPtr;
}
```

Comment: A heavy impedance mismatch.  Recover the raw interface pointer with Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(), cast the IntPtr to IUnknown* and call the _RecordsetPtr constructor.  One reference count too many, I think, call Marshal::Release()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant, I was able to find a solution:

```
_RecordsetPtr TraserInterface::GetDistributorRecordset()
{
    ADODB::Recordset^ recordset = TraserWrapper::Instance->traserInterface->DistributorRecordset);
    IntPtr recordsetIntPtr = Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(recordset);
    IUnknown* unknown = (IUnknown*)(void*)recordsetIntPtr;
    _RecordsetPtr recordsetPtr(unknown);
    return recordsetPtr;
}
```

Comment: You'd better check for memory leaks.  Write a little test app that does this a million times.